# Front and backend not loading properly

Tags: error, theme, frontend, backend, installation

[image]

When I am opening my admin panel, the pages are not loading properly.please help me to resolve this error as soon as possible

Comment: try to use 127.0.0.1 url  like http://127.0.0.1/mg2/.....

Comment: Can you show your Chrome console errors please.

Answer (score 1):

Run below command to resolve this error.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Note : **var** and **pub** folder permission should be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Magento requires a TLD to operate correctly (could also be a Chrome issue, I'm not sure, in Magento 1.x this only happened in Chrome, but not in other browsers).

Try accessing your site on `127.0.0.1` (make sure to reflect this in your config settings as well), or setup a vhost so you can access it like `www.awesome.dev` or something.

Also: all the other suggestions like cache clearing and static content deployment might be required (unless you have developer mode enabled).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have well all the files in these two paths:

1. `skin/adminhtml/default/default/{images, menu.css, boxes.css ...}`
2. `skin/frontend/{yourpackage}/{themename}/{css, images...}`

> NB: the rights of access to the `skin` file should be `755`